# If $a+d>b+c$, where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers, then which option is correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> A) $a,b,c,d$ are in AP
>
> B) $\frac 1a, \frac 1b, \frac 1c, \frac 1d$ are in AP
>
> C) $(a+b), (b+c), (c+d), (a+d)$ are in AP
>
> D) $(a+b), (b+c), (c+d), (a+d)$ are in HP

Now, there isn’t much info given, so I will try to eliminate the options

A can’t be right be $a+d=b+c$

Option A) was the only once that could be eliminated without any doubt. I am unsure about the rest of them.

Comment: Surely you can come up with counterexamples to $A$ and $B$, no?

Comment: None. $a=2$, $b=c=d=1$

Comment: @lulu and to C and D

Comment: Are you saying that none of the options are correct and that $(a,b,c,d)=(2,1,1,1)$ is a counterexample to all of them?

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Seems to me that something is wrong with the question.  Did you leave off any assumptions?

Comment: @lulu I have the printed solution with me, but it makes no sense at all.

Comment: I think there has to be missing information.  Simply knowing that $a+d>b+c$ says nothing at all about progressions.  If one of the options were true, then replacing $b$ with, say, $b-\epsilon$  retains the inequality but breaks the progression.